# Unable to pass boolean in URL

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, myfaces

I have 2 pages, `inputForm.xhtml` and `outputPage.xhtml`.

In `inputForm.xhtml`, there are 1 textfield and 1 checkbox. When user clicks submit button, the values are passed to `outputPage.xhtml` in URL.

The value of textfield can be passed correctly. However, no matter the checkbox is checked or not, the parameter in URL is always false.

e.g. `http://localhost:8080/jsf-web/outputPage.xhtml?c=false&n=franz`

I am using myFaces 2.1.13. I really have no idea how to fix that. Thanks.

`inputForm.xhtml`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="n" value="#{inputFormBean.name}" />
    <f:viewParam name="c" value="#{inputFormBean.nameUppercase}" />
</f:metadata>

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p>Name: <h:inputText value="#{inputFormBean.name}" /></p>
        <p>Name uppercase: <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{inputFormBean.nameUppercase}"/></p>
        <p><h:commandButton action="output_page" value="Submit" /></p>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

`outputPage.xhtml`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="n" value="#{outputPageBean.name}" />
    <f:viewParam name="c" value="#{outputPageBean.nameUppercase}" />
</f:metadata>

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h3>Welcome #{outputPageBean.nameUppercase ? outputPageBean.name.toUpperCase() : outputPageBean.name}!!</h3>
</h:body>
</html>
```

`faces-config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd" 
    version="2.0">

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>output_page</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/outputPage.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect include-view-params="true"/>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

`InputFormBean.java`

```
package com.franzwong.jsfweb;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class InputFormBean {
    private String name;
    private boolean nameUppercase;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public boolean isNameUppercase() {
        return nameUppercase;
    }
    public void setNameUppercase(boolean nameUppercase) {
        this.nameUppercase = nameUppercase;
    }
}
```

`OutputPageBean.java`

```
package com.franzwong.jsfweb;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class OutputPageBean {
    private String name;
    private boolean nameUppercase;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public boolean isNameUppercase() {
        return nameUppercase;
    }
    public void setNameUppercase(boolean nameUppercase) {
        this.nameUppercase = nameUppercase;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I tried primitive int and it is passed as 0 no matter what value I input.

Therefore, I tried Boolean, Integer and found that the value I input can be passed correctly in URL.